# SlidesJs and ColorBox not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, lightbox, colorbox

I've been trying to solve a wierd error i get when i try to apply a SlideJs script onto a container of thumbnails that uses colorbox to show.

I have 2 slideshow that use SlideJs, and the problem doesn't seems to be there.

Here is my current code :

```
<div id="services_slideshow">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="services_slideshow">

            <div class="slides_container2">

                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="images1.jpg" class="gallery"><div class="ss_1"></div></a>
                    <a href="images2.jpg" class="gallery"><div class="ss_2"></div></a>
                    <a href="images3.jpg" class="gallery"><div class="ss_3"></div></a>
                    <a href="images4.JPG" class="gallery"><div class="ss_4"></div></a>
                    <a href="images5.JPG" class="gallery"><div class="ss_5"></div></a>
                </div> <a href="#" class="prev2"><div class="prev"></div></a>
            <a href="#" class="next2"><div class="next"></div></a>

        </div> <!-- .services_slideshow -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- #servicees_slideshow -->
```

To call this, i use the :

```
$(function(){
            $('.water_slideshow').slides({
                preload: true,
                preloadImage: 'images/loading.gif'
            });

            $('.services_slideshow').slides({
                preload: true,
                preloadImage: 'images/loading.gif',
                next: 'next2',
                prev: 'prev2',
                container: 'slides_container2'
            });
        });
```

This function above call the 2 slideshow.
If i remove the second call, all my thumbnails show up normally, but not in a slideshow, and if i apply it, everything just dissapear. (Although, the Arrows are there, and the pagination also)

The first slideshow uses the default value (and so my components), such as next, prev, slides_container...

Now i was wondering if somone already had a same issue as i had, in order to get this solved !

thanks for any help!

For further information on colorbox, here is how i call it :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({ 
            opacity:0.5 ,
            scalePhotos:'true',
            maxWidth:'900px',
            maxHeight:'500px',
            rel:'group1'
        });});
```

Again, everyting works without calling the slideshow, and when called, nothing is shown !